# RewriteRule in .htacess to have all strings except some load one file and the other strings load another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /category1|category2|category3|category4/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?!category1|category2|category3|category4) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article.php?slugId=$1 [L]
```

I want to have the following links working to load the `category.php` file with the corresponding value for the category parameter:

`website.com/category1`

`website.com/category2`

`website.com/category3`

`website.com/category4`

And I want the rest of the strings in the format of `website.com/string` to load the `article.php` file with the string as its parameter.

Whenever I search for any of the categories it works fine. However, if I search for any other string it redirects me back to index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples and attempts, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (category1|category2|category3|category4) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(category1|category2|category3|category4) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article.php?slugId=$1 [L]
```